# How do you add a "------" break line into an SQL database?

Tags: php, sql, menu, drop-down-menu

I have a php code in where I am pulling a list of names from a database. As of now there are three names on the top, I want to show a dotted line separating the top three names from the rest. Sort of like how some sites do for the US, UK, Canada, etc, then the rest of the world under the line break?

Same concept, except I am doing it with companies.

So it would look like this:

1. Company 1
2. Company 2
3. Company 3

----------

1. Company 4
2. Company 5
3. Company 6
4. Company 7
5. Company 8
6. etc......

Is this possible?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Wheat exactly is your question? Where do you want to insert these? I assume you don't want to insert them into the database, but display them on the page, in which case it's a simple matter of keeping a counter, and when that equals 3, printing a bunch of -'s, or even better, a <hr>, and if you wanna go really semantic, putting the first 3 in a separate element with a border-bottom:#000 css style.

Comment: Why dont you post your code you are seeking to change here, so that its easier for people and they wont have to guess.... -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it inside your loop ( I assume thats how you print it)

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) { // replace your loop here

  if($i==3) {
  //print your dashes
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

why would you want to do that (put a hr tag into your db)? just `echo` your dashes when done with the first set of results from your query.

Comment: I have over 150 companies, I want the top three to be separated from the rest, something like what you are suggesting won't work.

Comment: take a look at footy's post below, that should solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

Add them when you're retrieving and outputting your data.

Comment: Actually I am asking, I have an SQL list in where needs to be shown as a pulldown menu in PHP, I want to know how to make it so that the pulldown menu shows a "-----" line to break up the three top companies over the other 150+ majority. So the end user doesn't have to go search for it.

Comment: php pulldown menu?! I think you're not giving enough information, php has no such concept.

Comment: Krelin, Yes there is: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms11.htm

Comment: As well as here too: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=183307.0

Comment: Matt, there is. I said *PHP* has no such concept. How was I to know you're referring to `HTML` `select` element? So, when you're outputting your `option` lines you should output whatever you want for a break after the third one.

Comment: ' <?php
 $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
      $mysqli->select_db('orders');

      $result = $mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM comp");

      echo "<SELECT name='comp'>\n";
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<option value='{$row['userid']}'>{$row['name']}</option>\n";   
      }
      echo "</select>\n";

      $result_close();

      ?>'

Here is the code... I'm using PHP/XHTML... I figured if people understood I was using PHP they would understand I'm encapsulating HTML into it.

Comment: There's **a lot** of ways to do menus on the client side. Besides, I'd also figure that if you're using php and html you're capable of adding a counter and putting the whatever break you want into it and that my answer is enough to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

A field in an SQL database should correspond to a value and not be concerned with formatting information. There is multiple ways to achieve the result you're after. The simplest being just to insert a *if statement* checking for the third entry and insert the additional delimiter on that iteration.

Usually, this is supposed to be handled in your php code and not added to the database.